# Name from XAML file not in current context in cs file

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and I am trying to build a Xamarin project. I created a Blank XAML App project. I went went to MainPage.xaml file and added an x.Name to the boilerplate Label like so:

[image]

In the MainPage.xaml.cs file I attempt to change the text of that Label by referencing that name `hello`:

[image]

VS does not seem to like this as I get an error:

> The name "hello" does not exist in the current context.

[image]

How can I access the names in the XAML file? I've tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `x:Name` instead of `x.Name`. `x` is the namespace you have declared with `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"` and if you want to use something declared in this namespace, you have to use `x` followed by a colon and than the class or attribute name.

```
<Label x:Name="hello" 
       Text="Welcome to Stackoverflow" 
       VerticalOptions="Center" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

Comment: Hi -- Your answer helped me understand, but I still have the same issue.   I'm using VS2017 ver 15.6.4, and I get the red underline, and message saying "The name 'hello' does not exist in the current context."  This is nearly the ONLY change I made since creating a new project.  But the project does compile and run!  This is frustrating for a newbie to Xamarin

Comment: Hmm at leat after the first compile it should be there. Do you use Resharper? Sometimes Resharper adds these lines :( Can you have a look at your file system and look for `obj/xyz/Namespace.PageName.xaml.g.cs`. In this file you should see a partial class. Does it contain your field?

Answer (score 0):

As @Sven-Michael Stübe noticed first you need to swap your `x.Name` declaration (which is incorrect) with `x:Name`.

Then, right click on your project and click `build` (or **⌘K** shortcut on Mac) to allow the complier see your name declaration. The red underline should disappear afterwards.